# How can I know the next value of the Django queryset without having to loop and store values?

Tags: json, django, django-queryset

I'm writing a website using Django and Vue.js. Although I am admittedly a beginner at both, I find this surprising that I can't seem to be able to know, beforehand the value of the next item of a queryset. I need to know if there is a way to do it in Django. For instance, I perform a search on the database, it returns a queryset, and I start to call the elements of the queryset one after the other. Is there a way to know the next beforehand?

```py
   def fetch_question(request):
       question_id = request.GET.get('question_id', None)
       response = Question.objects.filter(pk=question_id)
```

Comment: Why do you have to access the next object in the queryset?

Answer (score 0):

Django querysets are iterables, so you can retrieve their iterator with the `iter()` function, then apply `next()` to the iterator:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> qs = User.objects.all()
>>> it = iter(qs)
>>> next(it)
<User: root>
>>> next(it)
<User: toto>
>>> next(it)
<User: titi>
>>> next(it)
<User: tata>
>>>
```

Just beware that this consumes the iterator...

Another solution, if you want to iterate on `(current,next)` pairs is to use `zip()` (or it's lazy version `itertools.izip()` is using Python2 and having huge datasets):

```
>>> for current, next in zip(qs, qs[1:]):
...     print("current: {} - next : {}".format(current, next))
... 
current: root - next : tata
current: tata - next : titi
current: titi - next : toto
```

But I have to say that I really wonder why you think you'd want to "know, beforehand the value of the next item of a queryset"... I really fail to imagine what problem this is supposed to fix.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to know to have the ability to use the data in my JavaScript framework. Thanks for your answer tho.

Comment: Note that the usual way to thanks someone for an answer here is to upvote the answer (and - if it solved your issue - to accept it).

Comment: Also: "I was trying to know to have the ability to use the data in my JavaScript framework" doesn't explain why you think you need  a way to "get the next item in the queryset", and __I strongly suspect an XY problem here__ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).